# Marketing Cloud Personalisation String Truncates or Cuts Comparison Operator which is part of the String

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I'm looking for advice as I have 3 user codes that I want to give to each of my recipients via Email. Some codes contain comparison operators "<" and ">". But Marketing Cloud seems to cut the code every time it sees the comparison operator. What can I do so that the code shows as-is and won't get cut?

Ampscript in my email is %%code%%, where code is "=U<BV5=6Z6<C=" yet code gets cut at the "<" sign.

[![Result[image: ][1][1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by using '&lt' in the code instead of '<'.
If your data is stored in a data extension, you will have to replace this with '&lt' using SQL.
Please see below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, worked like a charm!